# How to build and use a bootstrap executable in a Cabal package

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to Cabalize a Haskell project in order to upload it to Hackage. It consists of one standard .hs file which builds a bootstrap executable, and eight nonstandard .lhs files which are processed by the bootstrap executable to yield the .hs files which build the production executable.

In other words, my project is a custom literate preprocessor (with HTML markup, code grooming, here documents) which is written in itself. It depends on a bootstrap version which can translate the literate code for the production version, but which is not suitable for general use. So I *do not* want the bootstrap version to be a separate package; it is meant to be used only once, here.

I have been using a Makefile, which is possible in Cabal but not in the spirit of Cabal. What is a clean way to do this, that takes maximal advantage of the generality of Cabal? I have not seen any suggestions for this in the online documentation, short of either rewriting Distribution.Simple or using a Makefile.

Answer (score 8):

I think that releasing your bootstrap executable as a separate package is the easiest solution, and there are [instructions available on how to integrate your custom preprocessor with Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-October/067601.html).

If you don't want to do that, try making your preprocessor part of `Setup.hs` (don't forget to set the build type to `Custom`!). You can run your preprocessor during the configure step. Look at how [`wxcore`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wxcore) does this.

Here's a working example (patterned after `wxcore`):

`Setup.hs`:

```
import Distribution.Simple
import Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo
import Distribution.Simple.Setup
import Distribution.PackageDescription

import Control.Monad (forM_)
import System.Directory (copyFile)
import System.FilePath (replaceExtension)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks { confHook = myConfHook }

-- Replace 'copyFile' with more complicated logic.
runMyPreprocessor :: FilePath -> IO ()
runMyPreprocessor abcFile = copyFile abcFile (replaceExtension abcFile ".hs")

myConfHook :: (GenericPackageDescription, HookedBuildInfo) -> ConfigFlags
              -> IO LocalBuildInfo
myConfHook (pkgDesc, hbi) flags = do
  let extraSrc = extraSrcFiles . packageDescription $ pkgDesc
  forM_ extraSrc runMyPreprocessor

  confHook simpleUserHooks (pkgDesc, hbi) flags
```

`my-preprocessor.cabal`:

```
name:                my-preprocessor
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Custom
cabal-version:       >=1.8
extra-source-files:  Main.abc

executable my-preprocessor
  main-is: Main.hs
  build-depends:       base < 5
```

`Main.abc`:

```
module Main
       where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello"
```

Comment: Nice! I'm experimenting with this now. My bootstrap preprocessor code is quite short; one option would be for me to simply include it in Setup.hs!